# How to generate a custom word document using excel data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

Basically we have to make meeting agendas for our conferences (where many firms and attend) and it's a round table discussion in which one firm is addressed at a time. The general layout is:

```
1.) Firm 1 - Representative
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
2.) Firm 2 - Representative
bullet point
bullet point
bullet point
3.) Firm 3 - Representative
etc. etc.
```

My company has to make these frequently and the Firm and representatives are all held in excel files. Is there a way to quickly generate this document?

Comment: The only possible answer to your question at this point is "probably". For a more definitive answer, we would need to know what the expected result is, exactly, what you've tried so far and how it failed to meet expectations. Some sample data would also be useful.

Comment: I think Mail Merge probably has the capability to do this, but I'm unfamiliar with it's exact functionality.

Comment: For a mail merge, the source data would be in Excel in columns for firm, representative, point 1, point 2, and so on (similar to columns for firm, street address, city, state, and zip). 

Another option is to format an Excel sheet to look like an agenda. Use formulas to copy information from other sheets to the agenda sheet. Print, or save as a PDF file, or paste into Word. 

Another option is to link text in a Word document to Excel. In Excel, select and copy. In Word, click Home > Paste > Link & Use Destination Styles. For more info search for "Copy from Excel to another Office program."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can accomplish this using mail merge.

Open your agenda template and go to the Mailings ribbon. Go to "Select Recipients" and choose "Use an Existing List" from the drop down menu. Once that is linked, you can insert fields in the document. Go to "Insert Merge Field" to select the fields to insert. Once you're finished, go to "Preview Results" to review the document. You'll want to select the correct record at this time, you can either jump through the records using the arrows to find it or go to "Edit Recipient List" for a custom list. After that, go to "Finish & Merge" and select "Edit Individual Documents" and select the choice for "Current Record" (if you have multiple, I don't recommend doing them all together because you'll still have to separate them into individual files). This will create the document and all you need to do is save it.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest two possible solutions, 1st is Non-VBA and another is VBA (Macro).*

**Method 1 Non VBA:**

- Create a single Sheet Workbook or better enter your meeting data in form of TABLE in Excel.
- Open blank file in Word.
- From **Insert Tab,** select **Object** from the  Drop down button.
- Then click **Create from File** tab, and Browse to the Workbook you wish to insert.
- Next is, to choose whether you wish the object to be linked or not.
- Finish with **Ok**.

**Method 2 VBA (Macro):**

**Note:**

- This needs a TABLE in Excel (better work with single Sheet file).
- In VB editor click **Tools** then **References** and add this **Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library**, finish with **Ok.**
- Create **Command Button** in Excel Sheet and *Copy & Paste* this code for it.

  ```
   Sub CommandButton1_click()


     Dim tbl As Excel.Range
     Dim WordApp As Word.Application
     Dim myDoc As Word.Document
     Dim WordTable As Word.Table


     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.EnableEvents = False


      Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("Table1").Range


      On Error Resume Next


       Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")


        Err.Clear

         If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")


         If Err.Number = 429 Then
  MsgBox "MS-Word not found, aborting now !!."
         GoTo EndRoutine
         End If

         On Error GoTo 0


         WordApp.Visible = True
         WordApp.Activate


         Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add


         tbl.Copy



    myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
          LinkedToExcel:=False, _
          WordFormatting:=False, _
          RTF:=False


          Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
           WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

          EndRoutine:

          Application.ScreenUpdating = True
          Application.EnableEvents = True


          Application.CutCopyMode = False

          End Sub
  ```

**N.B.** In this code **Sheet & Table** Names are editable.

Answer (score 0):

I found [python-docx-template](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) quite interesting:

Example `.docx` document:

```
My house is located
{%- if living_in_town -%}
 in urban area
{%- else -%}
 in countryside
{%- endif -%}
 and I love it.
```

```python
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("my_word_template.docx")
context = { 'company_name' : "World company" }
doc.render(context)
doc.save("generated_doc.docx")
```

For reading the data from excel see https://stackoverflow.com/q/22169325/873282.

Other alternative:

- Python mailmerge: https://pbpython.com/python-word-template.html --> https://pypi.org/project/docx-mailmerge/

Answer (score -2):

I've created this free tool to generate word documents from excel data , word template must have placeholders with the columns names as follow ${col_name}
Might be useful !
https://it-tun.com/exceltoword/